# Packing and unpacking two 32-bit integers into an unsigned 64-bit integer

Tags: c++, comparative-review, bitwise

Does this look good for combining/retrieving two 32 bit integers (a type and an index) into/from an unsigned 64 bit integer (a unique ID)?

The point is to hide in the API the composition of the unique ID and allow its calculation to change later without changing the API (e.g. possibility to change later to consecutive 64 bit ids without changing API).

```
#include <limits>

uint64_t combine(uint32_t low, uint32_t high)
{
     return (((uint64_t) high) << 32) | ((uint64_t) low);
}

uint32_t high(uint64_t combined)
{
    return combined >> 32;
}

uint32_t low(uint64_t combined)
{
    uint64_t mask = std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max();
    return mask & combined; // should I just do "return combined;" which gives same result?
}
```

Or would a union approach like below be better? Is this `union` guaranteed to fit into 64 bits (e.g. guarantee no padding in the `struct`)?

```
union Id
{
    struct
    {
       uint32_t index; // lower 32 bits
       uint32_t type;  // upper 32 bits
    } split;

    uint64_t unique_id;
};
```

Here is some code I used to test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h> 
#include <sstream>

template <typename T>
std::string bits(T num)
{
    const int num_bits = sizeof(num) * 8;

    T maxPow = T(1) << (num_bits - 1);

    std::stringstream ss;

    for(int i=0; i < num_bits; ++i)
    {
        // print last bit and shift left.
        ss << (num & maxPow ? 1 : 0);
        if ((i+1) % 8 == 0) ss << " ";
        num = num << 1;
    }

    return ss.str();
}

void test1()
{
    {
        int in_low = -3;
        int in_high = 99;
        uint64_t combined = combine(in_low, in_high);
        assert( bits(in_high) + bits(in_low) == bits(combined) );
        assert( in_low == low(combined) );
        assert( in_high == high(combined) );
    }

    {
        uint32_t in_low = 3;
        int in_high = -99;
        uint64_t combined = combine(in_low, in_high);
        assert( bits(in_high) + bits(in_low) == bits(combined) );
        assert( in_low == low(combined) );
        assert( in_high == high(combined) );
    }

    {
        uint32_t in_low = std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max();
        int in_high = std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::min();
        uint64_t combined = combine(in_low, in_high);
        assert( bits(in_high) + bits(in_low) == bits(combined) );
        assert( in_low == low(combined) );
        assert( in_high == high(combined) );
    }    
}

void test2() {
    Id in; // would "Id in = {-3, 99};" be better? Is this legal C++03? Would a constructor be better?
    in.split.type = -3; 
    in.split.index = 99;

    std::cout << in.unique_id << std::endl; // prints 18446744060824649827
    std::cout << bits(in.split.type) << bits(in.split.index) << std::endl;
    std::cout << bits(in.unique_id) << std::endl; // prints 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111101 00000000 00000000 00000000 01100011
    assert(bits(in.split.type) + bits(in.split.index) == bits(in.unique_id));

    Id out;
    out.unique_id = in.unique_id;
    std::cout << int(out.split.type) << ", " << out.split.index << std::endl; // prints -3, 99

    assert(in.split.type == out.split.type);
    assert(in.split.index == out.split.index);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Could you add some background information about why you want to pack two numbers into a `uint64_t`? Why not use a `union` and `struct`, for example?

Comment: This is for exposing a unique id while hiding the fact that we are storing two integers (type and index) into a single integer.  It would be easier for the user of the api to use a uint64_t than to think about a struct and allows us to later change how we represent unique ids without changing the api.

Comment: 200_success: by using a struct, did you mean something like this: http://ideone.com/s2dY3F ? I would assume that is less portable, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I was thinking of using a `union` instead of casting.

Comment: 200_success: I updated the question with a new implementation with unions.  This seems much clearer -- thank you.  The split variable name almost reads like a function call, which seems nice.  I haven't used unions before -- does this look like good naming convention/initialization/etc?

Comment: `union` can bring problems with align and padding, shifts and ORs can bring problems with byte order

Comment: Why not just change to consecutive 64bit ID's now? It seems like implementing bit packing now will make that harder later because there may be corner cases that are hard to translate or that don't get translated.

Comment: @borisbn what are "ORs"?

Comment: @JDiMatteo OR <-> `operator |`

Comment: @borisbn by byte order, you were referring to endianness, right?  how would endianness be a problem with shifts and ORs?  http://ideone.com/JUPtIV is the code run on little endian x86 , and here is the output on big endian sparc: http://pastebin.com/tx9p9DU0 .  the shifts and ORs produce exact same results on little and big endian

Comment: @JDiMatteo, yes, I referred endianness. If you'll print `combined` like this: `cout << combined << end` in function `test1` you'll see the difference at different platforms, however you can see the difference in `test2` when you printed `unique_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Union provides no guarantee of memory arrangement for this.  The C++ standard merely says that it's no bigger than the storage required for the largest element, and that it's designed to only have one active data member.

If you are only targeting one compiler and one architecture it may be okay to use it to translate between types, but it is definitely skiing off-piste.

I'd be tempted to wrap the whole thing up in a class and provide getter methods.  This insulates the user from changes in the implementation of the API in the most flexible way. And, use the bitwise operations (>>, <<, | and &) inside the class.  These operations will happen on a register, rather than in memory, and therefore do not suffer for endian issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not going to wrap it in a class, I would suggest bit shifting. It is more portable.

Using `union` is hard to make it correct and portable, and with no benefit over the bit-shift method. There is `#pragma pack` directive for dictating byte alignment, but it is not a standard directive. You also need to deal with endianness, because byte position of low and high 32-bit will be opposite between little-endian and big-endian platform.